# Install RTM Windows 8.1 with OEM Windows 8.0 license key?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

I have this HP 655 with Windows 8.0 pre-installed. I want to install the Windows 8.1 *mini upgrade*. But it's not showing up in Store. I can see updates for various apps, but not what I'm looking for. There is a whole Microsoft support article on this, I know, I've been there, done the reading. As usual (referring to Service Packs) they ask you to get other updates first, but this computer has all the latest updates but still, no Windows 8.1 *update* is offered.

Is it really necessary to have a Microsoft account to get Windows 8.1 for free?... Anyway!

I asked HP to send me a RTM copy of Windows 8.1 but they said they could not do that. I was wondering if i could use the OEM key that came with the computer, get my own hard copy of Windows 8.1 and activate it using the OEM key? Will it blend?....

**Update:**

After scrolling up and down on the Microsoft support page and reading the wall of text, a link popped up on the page that directs to the Store and the Windows 8.1 upgrade (`ms-windows-store:WindowsUpgrade`). See the screenshot below.

[image: a]

If you're having the same problem, I suggest that you try running this line from the Run prompt. See if that brings up the Windows 8.1 upgrade for you. It should take you to the Store and show you the upgrade option and there will be a Download button. *You might need to log in with a Microsoft account.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows 8 and 8.1 keys are not interchangeable.

...That being said, if you have a Windows 8 enable laptop from HP, Windows 8.1 may detect the HP Tags and just activate - I can't say for certain as I haven't had a chance to test.

Also, you do need a Microsoft account... Also, please check that it is OEM you have and not VLK... If you do have VLK, [I wrote a little guide here](http://blog.williamhilsum.com/2014/03/how-to-upgrade-windows-8-volume-license.html).

Comment: The "Product ID" number ends with "AAOEM". So that makes it OEM then, right?

Comment: That would be the last group of the digits. On [Microsoft community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/how-to-tell-if-windows-is-retail-or-oem/ea57d733-716d-4c9e-ba86-233be13545de) page they say it should be listed as the second group of digits. But I guess that applies only to Windows 7?

Comment: But I got it now, Windows 8.1 upgrade is downloading in Store right now. *It's taking very long time though. After 2 hours it's only at 58% complete (approx. 3.6 GB) over a 12 Mbps downlink.* I hope it will get installed by the end of the day. I'm not sure about Microsoft account. I was able to access the Store without providing any account information. Maybe it already was in there, maybe not... don't know for sure.

Comment: A much faster way to get up the Windows 8.1 upgrade is to run the line `ms-windows-store:WindowsUpgrade` from Run prompt. I just tested it and it works.